# Default value polymorphic associations doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, default-value, polymorphic-associations

I have a modified version of the [prototypical polymorphic model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  before_save :default_value

  private

  def default_value
    Rails.logger.debug("*** Setting default value ***")
    # Set default values here
  end
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Here I've tried to set the default values for the `Picture` model, as [suggested in an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722206/182048).

Problem is, the `default_value` method isn't called when `Employee` or `Product` is being saved.

I can confirm that the db is set up correctly, because I ran this in rails console:

```
emp = Employee.create() # Creating Employee.id == 1
emp.pictures.count # == 0
Picture.create(imageable_id: 1, imageable_type: "Employee") # Here, setting defaults works fine
Employee.find(1).pictures.count # == 1
```

So the question is: why doesn't `default_value` get called when I save an `Employee` or a `Product`?

Comment: What do you mean by "save an `Employee` or a `Product`"? Based on your example I see no reason why those two classes would inherit methods from `Picture`. What do you want to be able to do?

Comment: Thank you for your comment ptd! It just dawned on me that I was hoping that this setup should behave more like an "inheritance", but as I wrote in the comment of the accepted answer, I now understand why it can't do what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks work the same way from `console` or `server`. This callback is triggered only if the object is being saved.

If you save an `Employee` it will change the value of the child on save, only if any attribute is changed in the child. Example:

```
emp = Employee.first
emp.pictures.first.foo = "bar" # assuming that you have a column foo in pictures table
emp.save # will save the picture and trigger the callback `before_save`
```

---

But if you have the following scenario, then the pictures will not be saved:

```
emp = Employee.first
emp.save # will save only emp
```

---

If you need to save all the pictures for some reason, you can do the following:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  before_save :default_value

  def default_value
    self.pictures.update_all(foo: "bar")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks mohameddiaa27. I realized I was hoping `Employee` and `Product` "inherit" (in a behavioral sense) `Picture`s methods, but that can't possibly work. What would happen if one kept saving an `Employee` multiple times? Should it create a new record in `Picture` for each save? The behavoir, as it stands, makes sense to me. Thanks for your effort! :)